# SSIS data validation and Cleaning

Tags: ssis, validation

I need to do like this

Client puts data in FTP folder (data can be in these 3 format- .txt, .csv or .xls),  The SSIS package need to pull data from ftp and check the data file for correct format such as  last name not empty, phone is 10 digit, zip code is 5 digits, Address is not more than 20 character length etc etc)
After checking data file, if everything okay it should load file   in dev. database, if not I need to run some cleaning quires (like taking first 5 digit for zip etc) and load data, if some column is missing, it need to send email to client  asking different data file

Till now, I do this task by manually importing file and running lot of sql queries, which is  time consuming. My manager asked me to write SSIS package to automate this process

I am fairly new in SSIS, can someone give me SSIS package design idea (I mean which task to use at which sequence etc) so I can try and learn
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

Configure tasks to send errors caused by bad data to a separate file. This will identify problem rows while letting the good stuff to continue. You can also use the conditional split to redirect rows with bad data such as blank rows.

The Derived Column Transformation is handy to trim, format, slice, and dice data.

Use the Event Handler to send emails if a given condition is true.

Use the logging features. Very helpful in sorting out something that went sideways while you were sleeping.